# PHP put two query result on table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to queries to mysql database. 
This queries return to array values and i need to put this arrays in a table. 
The first row is related to second row.
The first query contain a group of all workplaces in production line.
The second query contain classification of the workers on each workplace that production line, and the workplace.

Lets see:

First Row - Workplaces

Second Row - Classification

[image]

The table on link represent the classification of the worker on every workplace.

I need to relation the first row with second row, but a don't know how i i do this.

Please Help.

Comment: why my question is unclear or not useful?

Comment: Seems like you should be getting all this data with a single LEFT JOIN query.

Comment: I have a simple query to return all the workplaces to put on table head. And have a second query to return the workplaces and classification of worker on certain workplaces, the second query use inner joins

Comment: I am suggesting that perhaps you you LEFT JOIN all the workplaces to the the worker location information.  That way you have a single correlation of all workplaces along with the worker locations. To get more specific advice, it would probably help if you show your database table information as well as your current code.

Comment: You can be right, this can be the answer. I will try a and comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query i can search the workplace and classification

```
    SELECT DISTINCT PT.ID_WORKPLACE, F.WORKER, F.CLASSIFICATION, PT.LINE 
    FROM WORKPLACE_FORMATION PF 
    LEFT JOIN FORMATION F ON PF.ID_FORMATION=F.ID_FORMATION 
    RIGHT JOIN WORKPLACE_FORMATION PT ON PF.ID_WORKPLACE=PT.ID_WORKPLACE 
    WHERE F.WORKER=1234  
    OR F.WORKER IS NULL 
    AND PT.LINE=126;
```

And PHP code put the data in table:
    ';

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td colspan="'.$postos_numero.'">Postos de Trabalho</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr align="center" valign="middle" class="tabelas">';
while ($registo_postos = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_pesquisa_entre_datas))
    {  

echo '<td>';
echo "".$registo_postos['POSTO']."";
        echo '</td>';}
        echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr align="center" valign="middle" class="tabelas">';
while ($registo_postos_d = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_pesquisa_colab_linha_desmp))
    { 
if ($registo_postos_d['DESEMP'] == NULL){

echo '<td>';
echo "<img height='20' width='20' src='./img/x.png' title='Sem formação neste posto de trabalho'>";
echo '</td>'; 

}elseif($registo_postos_d['DESEMP'] == 1){

echo '<td>';
echo "<img height='20' width='20' src='./img/!.png' title='Produz com supervisão'>";
echo '</td>';

}elseif($registo_postos_d['DESEMP'] == 2){

echo '<td>';
echo "<img height='20' width='20' src='./img/v.png' title='Produz sem supervisão e está apto a dar formação'>";
echo '</td>';

        }}
     echo '</tr>';

echo '</table>';

?>
```

see the result on this image:
http://s18.postimg.org/4i163rtuh/image_result.png

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database tables, it is hard to give specific answer, but generally I would look to use a left join of your workplaces to the worker locations.  For this example, I will assume a table structure like this:

workplaces:

```
workplace_id - autoincrment primary key
workplace_label - name to be used for display
[other workplace data fields] - not important for this example

workplace_id   workplace_label
1              0001
2              0002
...
```

workers:

```
worker_id - autoincrement primary key
[other worker data fields] - not important for this example
```

workers_workplaces:

```
workplace_id - part of compound primary key with worker_id
worker_id - part of compound primary key with workplace_id
```

A query to get the data you are looking for could look like this:

```
SELECT
    wp.workplace_label AS workplace,
    COUNT(wwp.worker_id) AS worker_count
FROM workplaces AS wp
LEFT JOIN worker_workplaces AS wwp
    ON wp.workplace_id = wwp.workplace_id
GROUP BY workplace
```

This would return data like

```
workplace     worker_count
0001          0
0002          0
0003          2
0004          1
...
```

Note, I didn't actually use the `workers` table in the query is it was unnecessary.  I just wanted to explain the existence of this table so you could see how the `workers_workplaces` tables relates the two other tables together.

When reading out the result set in PHP you would likely do something like:

```
$workplace_array = array();
while ($row = /* your DB fetch here */) {
    $workplace_array[$row['workplace'] = $row['worker_count'];
}
```

This gives you an associative array with workplace labels as keys.  If you want to just get the workplace labels (for example to display your header row in table. You can easily get that like:

```
$workplace_labels = array_keys($workplace_array);
```

Comment: please see this image schema http://s30.postimg.org/n3uu1etlt/Captura_de_tela_2014_10_30_14_26_21.png

Comment: OK, this query return all workplaces, worker classification and worker id. I will try put it on html table to do the same way in question image. SELECT DISTINCT PT.ID_WORKPLACE, F.WORKER, F.CLASSIFICATION, PT.LINE
FROM WORKPLACE_FORMATION PF
LEFT JOIN FORMATION F ON PF.ID_FORMATION=F.ID_FORMATION
RIGHT JOIN WORKPLACE_FORMATION PT ON PF.ID_WORKPLACE=PT.ID_WORKPLACE
WHERE F.WORKER=1234 
OR F.WORKER IS NULL
AND PT.LINE=126;